# can't mount an encrypted Volume on an M1 Mac. Works fine on Intel Macs. Known Issue?

Tags: disk-utility, encryption, mount, apple-silicon

Is this a known issue with M1 Macs and encrypted drives?

What steps should I attempt to mount this volume?

Encrypted drive will not mount on M1 Mac. Mounts on my intel Macs no problems.

It’s Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) format and I used Disk Utility to create the volume using standard Apple encryption.

It hangs DU when I ask DU to mount the volume, sometimes even just plugging it into the M1 Mac causes DU to hang.

On the rare times Finder asks for a password for the volume, it beachballs the Finder/Mac. When I try and mount it using DU or Terminal it doesn’t work, in DU it hangs DU and I have to force quit DU. Apple support senior advisor still cannot get to the bottom of it. Seems to be an M1 Mac and/or Big Sur issue. I’ve already allowed 3rd kernel extensions on this Mac so that’s not it.

This is not a Time Machine drive. (people often assume it might be). On the Intel Mac I can connected with a USB3 cable into a USB2 hub (older Mac) or via a OWC TB2 hub in one of the USB ports. ON the 13' M1 MBA I'm going directly into the USB3 port via an adapter (TB3 to USB/HDMI adapter). The M1 Mac can see the drive but not mount it from terminal, disk utilities or in Finder. If I ever get to the point of being able to enter the encryption key, it hangs the app doing it, or the Mac entirely.

```
  $ diskutil list external
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *960.2 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage magic-carpet            959.9 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3

/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS magic-carpet           +959.5 GB   disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                 F37357F2-53C0-4926-BC59-431301F9A208
                                 Unlocked Encrypted

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        +49.1 MB    disk4
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS AnyMP4 Screen Record... 49.1 MB    disk4s2
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the result of terminal command ``diskutil list external`` from your Intel Mac? What is the external disk connector type : USB-3, Thunderbold and eventual adapter?

Comment: thx, I've done that now @Jean_JD

Comment: Have you try boot your M1 in Safe mode, then plug and mount the drive?

Comment: I think so, I had to go into safe mode to allow a 3rd party kernel extension (for pCloud) around the same time and pretty sure I checked for it then also. I'll double check that though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no known, general issue with encrypted drives for the M1 Mac.

The symptoms you're describing sound very much like a corrupted file system. Together with bugs in the operating system's file system code, it can lead to these issues. I would run a file system check on the drive when unmounted. You can do this from your Intel Mac.

You can run the file system check from the Terminal like this:

```
sudo fsck_hfs -f /dev/disk3
```

Note that this assumes the file system is HFS+ and that it is mounted as /dev/disk3 (as in your screenshot). Use Disk Utility first to find the actual disk number.

The problem could also be of a hardware nature. I would suggest trying to connect the disk using the exact same adapter to another PC/Mac and see if that works. As you're using different methods of connecting the disk currently, it is difficult to know if it could be a hardware issue or not.

Comment: thanks for the info, I don't have another Mac with a USB-C port, but I'll endeavour to borrow one for to complete this test. 

Do practical solutions include Disk Warrior (using my Intel Mac)? My understanding is that unlike other disk repair apps, DW works exclusively on the files system registry. Is it simplest just backup the files, then reformat using the external SSD in question using the M1 Mac? (I'd rather avoid that if there's other solutions).

Comment: Yes, you can try Disk Warrior instead of fsck, if you rather want to use that. DW is not different from fsck in that it “exclusively works on the files system registry”, no - that’s not how things work. Your suggestion in backupping and reformatting would definitely work as well - I would always ensure that you have backups as you might have a corrupted file system.

Comment: cheers @jksoegaard … will try some things and report back.